# Sony TA-SP55 only ampli

Tags: amplifier

I've got a Sony TA-SP55.I've saved only the amp, and I'm sorry to throw it away: does anyone know how I can "implanting" a jack and use it as a simple jack -> amp -> speakers? 
Reading the block diagram of the circuit I found the + left and right input, but not the left, then I dn't know if it will need to be connected all, I hope not!

Comment: Is it broken? Do you have a schematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tuner has an AUX input, I suggest you use that.

[image]

If the audio source is not line-level, I would consider using an appropriate attenuator, DI-box or pre-amp.

There is a proprietary interconnect between the tuner and the amp. If you don't have the tuner, you might be able to work out whether any pins on the interconnect carry line-level audio (which seems very likely). This would be easier if you have the service manual or a tuner (ironically). Alternatively you can open up the amp and try to understand the circuitry near the interconnect.

The [service manual](http://www.minidisc.org/manuals/sony/service/sony_MDS-SP55_service_manual.pdf) for an optional MD unit shows a pin-out:

[image]

At the right hand side are outputs that might be line-level audio. You could try feeding a line-level audio signal to the corresponding pins on the amp connector.

Of course it may be that the amp won't work unless some appropriate digital signals / proprietary communications take place between the audio components using pins 12-14.

Comment: Yes I had got the same idea, but there are only two outputs: the left and right plus (+) signal, but the less (-)?

Comment: @DPD: Perhaps it's a simple stereo audio signal not a differential/balanced signal? In which case AGND is the common audio ground connection for both channels.